# How in Laravel run JavaScript code stored in php variable?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

In the livewire component, I have the script tag:

```
<script>
{!! $script !!}
</script>
```

Let's say the `$script` variable contains `console.log('test');`

It is executed once - no surprise [documentation](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/inline-scripts) explains this. The recommendation is to emit a custom event and listen to it, but the problem is that it does not work with code in a variable.
In other words, this works:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('custom-event', () => {
        console.log('test');
    })
</script>
```

but this does not:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('custom-event', () => {
        {!! $script !!}
    })
</script>
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What is it actually outputting into the event listener function?

Answer (score 0):

try this

in component

```
public $foo;

$this->dispatchBrowserEvent('custom-event', ['foo' => $this->foo]);
```

in view

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('custom-event', event => {
          alert('here value foo: ' + event.detail.foo);
          console.log(event.detail.foo);
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ->

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('custom-event', () => {
        {!! json_encode($script) !!}
    })
</script>
```

I hope it was helpfull! :)